# How to specify tcl compiler in Tkinter library?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I'm trying to compile tcl scripts in python, and using tkinter library, but there're some tcl libraries not in the standard tcl libs, is there a way to specify tcl compiler in tkinter or to install new tcl package in tkinter ?

I didn't find any questions similar to this one, hence I didn't find any similar solutions.

As an example, I'm trying to use tclvisa library in tcl, which is not a standard lib.

```
import tkinter

tclsh = tkinter.Tcl()

tclsh.eval("package require tclvisa")
```

The above code generates error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
tclsh.eval("package require tclvisa")
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package tclvisa
```

Solution:

Put tcl lib in python/tcl and it works for me

Comment: what happens when you run the code you've posted in the question?

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi,  I have edited the question  it shows the error says can't find package.

Comment: Python hides this pretty far away from you. So I think the answer is: you don't:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c

Comment: You can find where packages need to be installed by running `print(tclsh.eval("set auto_path"))`. You can also add to `auto_path` to tell it to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tcl global variable `auto_path` contains a Tcl list of directories to look for packages in. Add a directory to it using `lappend` as you probably don't want to remove the existing entries in it:

```
tclsh.eval("lappend auto_path /path/to/add")
tclsh.eval("package require tclvisa")
```

You can also control this by setting the [`TCLLIBPATH` environment variable](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M8) before loading the Tkinter package. Assuming that Tkinter doesn't interfere with that itself…